# How to Check If a String Contains a Specific Word with uppercase and lowercase in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

i want to check the string contains "SDN", whether it is uppercase or lowercase such as "sdn", "Sdn", "sDN and so on, how can I get all that?

I using strpos($company_name, 'SDN') now and only can get the "SDN".

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: Just put both the variable and the comparison in To Lower or To Upper case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting both to the same case:

```
strpos(strtoupper($company_name), 'SDN');
```

You could also use `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/SDN/i', $company_name);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php